# On iOS, if a view controller has no view yet, why does NSLog(@"self.view is %p", self.view) crash?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

If a new iOS project is created with an Empty App template in Xcode 4.3.2, and in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[FooViewController alloc] init];
```

and in `FooViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`, the following:

```
NSLog(@"self.view is %p", self.view);
NSLog(@"self.view is %@", self.view);
```

will print out the view, so it looks like the default `loadView` will instantiate a view and assign it to `self.view`.

So if I override `loadView` with an all empty method, and comment out the second `NSLog` statement above, I expect the first `NSLog` statement to print out `0x0`, but instead the app crashed due to bad memory access right at that `NSLog` line.  Why would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the [`view` property in `UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/view) states:

> Because accessing this property can cause the view to be loaded automatically, you can use the `isViewLoaded` method to determine if the view is currently in memory.

It also has a link to [The View Controller Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW2), which states:

> The steps that occur during the load cycle are as follows:
>
> 1. The load cycle is triggered when the view controller's `view` property is accessed and the view is not currently in memory.
> 2. The view controller calls its `loadView` method. The default implementation of the `loadView` method does one of two things:
>
>    - If the view controller is associated with a storyboard, it loads the views from the storyboard.
>    - If the view controller is not associated with a storyboard, an empty `UIView` object is created and assigned to the `view` property.
> 3. The view controller calls its `viewDidLoad` method to allow your subclass to perform any additional load-time tasks.

So when you say:

> So if I override `loadView` with an all empty method

You're deliberately breaking the life cycle, because when your overridden version of `loadView` finishes, it should have loaded a view. Because it didn't, you get a crash.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, after a knee-jerk and obviously wrong answer, I tried this.  The Empty App template would not have a rootViewController, so I used a single screen template.  After running, I see that you are getting a stack overflow. In trying to access self.view, you are calling the view property on the superclass, which is then trying to load the view in order to return it, which is calling viewDidLoad, etc., as far as I can see.  The other NSLog statement does the same.

Comment: Yep, that's it.  I missed the overflow...I'm removing my answer.

Comment: thanks for the insight. When `self.view` is accessed... I thought that is just to return the `view` instance variable?  Since `view` is defined by `@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *view;` doesn't that make it just an instance variable?  If that's the case, then the accessor made by `@synthesize` should just return the instance variable... you mentioned the superclass trying to "load the view"... how does it try to load the view (from where?) when the view is nil?

Comment: See Shaggy Frog's better answer: The load cycle is triggered by accessing the view property when the view is not in memory. viewDidLoad is part of that cycle, so by accessing it there when there is no view, it is causing the recursion.